# how to refresh browser from Silverlight app located inside of a child aspx page

Tags: silverlight

I know there are methods to refresh the browser page from silverlight 
like HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(HtmlPage.Document.DocumentUri); OR
System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Document.Submit();
And these work fine when the container page use the total space in the page,
but what about when my silverlight app is located on a child page that belong to a some kind of master page? i.e. In the code bellow I have a page called Application.aspx that have three sections (main.aspx is where my silvelight app is located).

```
<frameset >
    <frame id=frameTitle name=frameTitle src="title.aspx" noResize scrolling="no"   frameborder="no" height="75" />
    <frame name="frameSpacer" id="frameSpacer" src="spacer.aspx" noresize scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"/>
    <frame id="frameMain" name="frameMain" src="main.aspx" noResize scrolling=no frameborder="no" />
</frameset>
```

How can I refresh Application.aspx and not just Main.aspx (when i use Document.Submit() i got a partial refresh for main.aspx)? using other method?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Solution: from the container aspx page we need to add a js function:

```
 function reload() {
        window.parent.location.reload(true);
    }
```

from silverlight: we need to add a call to the js function "reload"

```
HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("reload");
```